# How to get the E[x] and Var[x]?

Tags: probability-distributions

While several million cars drive on the Pennsylvania Turnpike over a holiday weekend, the number of passenger cars taking a specific exit off the Turnpike on Thanksgiving weekend averages $5$ per minute. Of those $50$% have only the driver; $30$% have $2$ people in the car; $10$% have three people and $5$% have $4$ people; and $5$% have $5$ people. Let X = the total number of people that are in the cars passing through a tollbooth at this exit in the next $10$ minutes. Find E(X) and Var(X). How to solve this problem? I don't have any clue about it.

Comment: Start from the definitions of expectation and variance.

Comment: Thank you. But then how about the pmf of the distribution? is it a poisson or gamma or what?

Comment: The more you try to clarify the body of your question, the better answers will come up.

Comment: Cars taking the exit sounds very much like a poisson process, don't you think? With the exception that cars have to be at least a second or three apart, of course.

Comment: Hint for the variance: $Var\left( \sum\limits_{i=1}^{5} w_i\cdot X_i\right)$ $=w_1^2\cdot Var(X_1)+w_2^2\cdot Var(X_2)+w_3^2\cdot Var(X_3)+w_4^2\cdot Var(X_4)+w_5^2\cdot Var(X_5)$, where $w_i$ are the weights and $X_i$ are the (independent) poisson distributed random variables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Total number of cars passing in 10 minutes is $10 \times 5 = 50.$ Hence,

\begin{align}
\mathbb{E}[X] & = 50 \times \left[\left( 1 \times \dfrac{50}{100} \right) + \left(2 \times \dfrac{30}{100} \right) + \left(3 \times \dfrac{10}{100}\right) + \left(4 \times \dfrac{5}{100} \right) + \left( 5 \times \dfrac{5}{100}\right)\right] \\
& = 50 \times (0.5 + 0.6 + 0.3 + 0.2 + 0.25) = 92.5
\end{align}